# How to use Oscar API Login with React JS or any JavaScript framework?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar, cookie-httponly

I use [Oscar API](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api) in my project.
It uses httponly cookies to log in and register and other options like add to basket.

All I need is to use it with react/next js project.
But I can't access cookies because of httponly cookies.
So please help me with oscar API authentication.

In my react js code I already use

> withcredentials true

when fetching from API.

in the Django setting I already use

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CRSF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE`  needs to pass a string data but I send None, all I need I send it as a string.

must use them when working with HTTP-only cookies with the Django rest framework.

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None" 
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://yourdomain',
]
```

in react js/ next js just use `withcredentials true` while fetch api.